# c# table not showing in .db3 file

Tags: c#, sqlite

I just started c# this month, and i have this problem when i tried to create a new database file (.db3), the table was created but not showing when i open it with sqlite studio. When i try again the system says the table is already exist but when i open the .db3 file the table is not inside, here is my code.

```
SQLiteConnection.CreateFile("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\newTable.db3");
SQLiteConnection createnew = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=newTable.db3; Version=3;");
createnew.Open();

string newtbl1 = "CREATE TABLE newtest (ID varchar(32) not null, frameId integer not null, posAttrib varchar(128) not null, attrib varchar(64), name varchar(200))";

                    
SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(newtbl1, createnew);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I tried to do some searching on google but I got nothing. I have no idea how to solve it and have very limited knowledge in c#, can anyone give me a hint or any keyword that i could search with? Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if you open the SQLiteConnection, do you open that one just created on the desktop or ist it one in the whatever working directory?

Try it this way:

```
string dbfile = @"C:\Users\user\Desktop\newTable.db3";
SQLiteConnection.CreateFile(dbfile);
SQLiteConnection createnew = new SQLiteConnection($"Data Source={dbfile}; Version=3;");
createnew.Open();

string newtbl1 = "CREATE TABLE newtest (ID varchar(32) not null, frameId integer not null, posAttrib varchar(128) not null, attrib varchar(64), name varchar(200))";

SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(newtbl1, createnew);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: This works, Thanks alot ! May I know what is the logic behind this? i see no much changes in the codes but still it works, im so confused

Comment: Sure - you saw the changes (one prepended, one altered, one effectively changed). The clue is, you did not connect to the db file you just created as intended. As mentioned in the answer you connected to something in the executables working directory.

Comment: Now i see! Does it have something to do with the @ and $ tags? i see them in several places but im not sure what does it use for

Comment: Ehm no, the point was your connection string ("Data Source=newTable.db3; Version=3;"), which didn't have the full path included. The @ in @"C:\Users\.." is [for avoid escaping all the backslashes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string). It's in this case the same as "C:\\Users\\..". The $ is a shorthand for inlineing variables called [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated). So $"{foo}" is pretty similar to string.Format("{0}",foo).

Comment: ok i see the points now, thank you so much for your patience and helping!